# How to deploy a Node.JS server to Microsoft Azure and using github to store source code?

Tags: node.js, azure

I want to use node.js server to Azure to create a collection and provides post, delete, put, get function.
How can I do?

Comment: I would like to see the procedure of doing this

Comment: Try checking the documentation on the Microsoft Azure site before asking here.

Comment: I am a total beginner, I am so exhausted to read such a large amount of words

Comment: Software development might not be the right career for you then. Here's a link to their [Nodejs tutorials](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/) which I found by simply googling "Microsoft Azure with Nodejs". It was the top link.

Comment: @loeghy10 - this is completely documented at azure.com (which is what SnareChops meant by checking the documentation), including complete-beginner documentation on deploying node apps to Azure web apps with github.

Comment: And seriously? "so exhausted to read such a large amount of words" ??? So you refuse to read what's already documented, and want us to type new words because you're exhausted???

Comment: Also: "create a collection and provides post, delete, put, get function" - this is a separate, and off-topic, question, where you're asking how to build your app (off-topic because it's opinion-based, and too broad).

Comment: @SnareChops thanks for helping, save me a lot of time to find the suitable reference

Comment: It wasn't me, it was Google.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/ when i reach 14, i can't see git url in the properties, how can i make it appear

Comment: Please create a new question with your issue, what you've tried, and what you are trying to accomplish. That or google, you might find what you're looking for.

Comment: @loeghy10, do you miss step 10-13? You need to create a git repo before using it.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT i did 10-13, but i can't see the element that shown in red cycle in the reference

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after you finishing the step 10-13 in [Create a Node.js web app in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/), you can find the git URL in the following 2 places. Please refer to the following captures:

1. in essentials portal:
   [image]
2. in properties portal:
   [image]

Comment: Does "i did 10-13, but i can't see the element that shown in red cycle in the reference" in your comment mean you cannot find where to set local git repo? or cannot find the URL after setting local git repo. In additional, you can try to leverage [old portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com), at your website manage portal, in **DASHBOARD** page, you can click `
Set up deployment from source control` under **quick glance** column to set up a local git repo